# Java return List of null instead of object

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, spring, jpa

I have a problem that I don't understand.
I have this code:

```
@Override
public List<MissionProfile> populateFilterMissionProfile(List<Integer> fleet, List<Integer> application, List<Integer> vehicle, List<String> dataSet, List<String> shift, List<String> drchannel, List<String> swVersion, String userName){ 
    //If vehicle is null (so not used into filter) than add the allowed vehicles (for the user) to the query to filter the acquisitions by the allowed applications
    if (vehicle==null) {
        vehicle =fleetHasUserRepository.getAllCarForUser(userName).stream().map(x->x.getIdCar()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    //Retrieve all the acquisitions for the specific parameters
    List<Acquisition> acquisitions = acquisitionRepository.advancedSearch(fleet, application, vehicle, null, dataSet, shift, null, null ,drchannel, swVersion);
    List<MissionProfile> missionProfiles = acquisitions.parallelStream().map(x->x.getMissionProfile()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    return missionProfiles;
}
```

This return list of null (it is called by a web services and return `{"status":true,"success":true,"result":[null,null],"error":null}`)

I use the same code in a lot of other method, the only difference is that the other use `List<String>` or `List<Integer>`.
I suppose tha tthe error is inside `advancedSearch` method, but if I put a `System.out.println(missionProfiles)` before the return or if I watch the variable with eclipse debug it works, otherwise it returns `null` (even if I write `missionProfiles.size()` doesn't work but with `missionProfiles.get(0).getidMissionProfile()` it works)
This is the database code

```
@Query("SELECT e "
            + "FROM Acquisition e "
            + " WHERE (COALESCE( :fleet ) is null OR e.car.fleet.fleetName.idFleetName in (:fleet) )"
            + " AND  (COALESCE( :application ) is null OR e.car.fleet.idFleet in (:application) )"
            + " AND (COALESCE( :vehicle ) is null OR e.car.idCar in (:vehicle) )"
            + " AND (COALESCE( :mp ) is null OR e.missionProfile.idMissionProfile in (:mp) )"
            + " AND (COALESCE( :dataset ) is null OR e.dataset in (:dataset) )"
            + " AND (COALESCE( :shift ) is null OR e.shift.idShift in (:shift) )"
            + " AND (:dateFrom is null OR  e.date >= :dateFrom) "
            + " AND (:dateTo is null OR  e.date <= :dateTo) "
            + " AND (COALESCE( :drchannel ) is null OR e.drChannelsConf in (:drchannel) )" 
            + " AND (COALESCE( :swVersion ) is null OR e.swVersion.idSwVersion in (:swVersion) )" )
    List<Acquisition> advancedSearch( @Param(value = "fleet") List<Integer> fleet,
            @Param(value = "application") List<Integer> application,
            @Param(value = "vehicle") List<Integer> vehicle,
            @Param(value = "mp") List<Integer> mp,
            @Param(value = "dataset") List<String> dataSet, 
            @Param(value = "shift") List<String> shift, 
            @Param(value = "dateFrom") Date dateFrom, 
            @Param(value = "dateTo") Date dateTo,
            @Param(value = "drchannel") List<String> drchannel,
            @Param(value = "swVersion") List<String> swVersionn );
```

I tried without stream and with `Thread.sleep(10000)` but the problem still present. Do you see where is the error?
This is the debug of acquisitions
[image]
this is the missionProfiles
[image]

Comment: is Aquisition an entity ?

Comment: @AmanChhabra yes, do you need to watch it?

Comment: Have you tried debugging what exactly comes in  List<Acquisition> acquisitions

Comment: Yes, I post the image, maybe the problem is that the object is null until it is used?

Comment: No that should not be the case. Where exactly you are getting null, I can see only some attributes to be null like idMissionProfile,missionProfile and note

Comment: yes, but if I print these values they are right

Comment: Then may be you should check the getters that you are calling when prinitng

Comment: the problem is the lazy property on the MissionProfile in Acquisition, with eager it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem about `Lazy` initializaion on the `acquisition` entity.
I added this row

```
missionProfiles.forEach(x->Hibernate.initialize(x.getMissionProfile()));
```

before the `return`